# MongoDB to Webpage

Tags: mongodb, charts, html

Let's say i have a sensor in the field from which i take the distances of a product i'm making. These information i'm storing it with mongoDB, and i want to print in a webpage a chart, for example a bar horizontal chart. How could i do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry to say this but this is illogical. As long as you are using Java driver, why do you want to draw data from mongo shell? By talking about 'webpage programming', do you refer to HTML/CSS/JS or do you also refer to the server side programming too?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I corrected the point about mongo shell, i meant java driver! And i refer to the HTML/CSS/JS. I'm sorry if I don't explain myself to well, i'm kind of new here.

Comment: Then do you have basic ideas about how to use Java to build a website?

Comment: I mean there are various kinds of tools that can help you build charts, some of them work in front end, like [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/). you can also find server side components which basically generate a image based on the data given. However, if you are also asking about how to build a website, then your question is kind of too wide to answer.

Comment: Ok, i use flot for making the charts. But the problem that i have is that i don't know how to take the data from the Mongo to build the chart with it.

Comment: that's the point. Flot works in your browser. How to send data from server side to client side depends on what technology (e.g. Java) you are using, and the framework (e.g. struts/servlet) you work with. That's a pretty wide topic to answer, not even related to mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client and your server are the same, and if you are the only one using your software, you can start mongod with the --rest option.

```
mongod --rest
```

Then you can access the REST API in JavaScript directly:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  rows = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).rows;
  // now you have an array of documents
 }
}
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:28017/myDB/myCol/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

More information here:
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Answer (score 0):

Develop a webserver that reads from your MongoDB database and produces chart images.

For a simple webserver, you can use Spark (http://sparkjava.com) and the JFreeChart library to generate chart images.

Alternatively, you can write PHP scripts, use the MongoDB API for PHP and use a PHP library for generating charts.

Then you can write your HTML websites that call your webserver to load the images:

```
<img src="http://myserver/chart/userdata/2016">
```

You have to follow this server-side approach because letting the web client directly connect to your MongoDB server is not a good idea ;-)

Comment: Your comment gave me kind of an idea, but i just edited the text to make it easier to understand. Could you read it again and help me?

Comment: If you want to use your client-side chart tool (Flot), use Spark to build a simple JSON API for your MongoDB collection. Then use a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest to access this API from the server. Use JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) to convert the JSON into an array. Then you can use this array to generate the chart on client-side.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would try to do that :)